# Transformations of Random Variables Question

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

I've been given the following problem:

If a random variable $X$ has probability density function $f_X (x)$ and cumulative distribution function $F_X (x)$, prove that $U = F_X (x) \sim$ uniform$(0,1)$

Ordinarily to solve a problem like this, I'd use the following method:

> $F_U (u) = Pr(U\leq u) = Pr(g(X) \leq u) = Pr(x \leq g^{-1} (u)) = F_X (g^{-1} (u))$

And then differentiate w.r.t $u$ to get $f_U (u)$. However in this case, I am not sure whether I can find $g^{-1}$ because $F_X (x)$ doesn't seem to necessarily be 1-to-1 even over the range of values $X$ can take. (I can see that $F_X (x)$ is increasing but not necessarily strictly increasing)

How should I choose $g^{-1}$ in this case? Or is there a better method to solve this specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $\ F_X\ $ to be strictly increasing for the result to hold, but you do need it to be continuous, which it will be if it has a density function.  If $\ F_X\ $is continuous, then $\ P\big(F_X(X)\le y\big)=P\big(F_X(X)<y\big)\  $, because $\ \big\{x\ \big|\ F_X(x)=y\big\}=[a, b]\ $ for some $\ a,b\ $ with $\ b\ge a\ $, and $\ P\big(F_X(X)=y\big)=$$P(a\le X\le b)=$$F_X(b)-F_X(a)=$$0\ $.  But $\ F_X(X)<y\Leftrightarrow X\in F_X^{-1}\big([0, y)\big)\ $, and $\ F_X^{-1}\big([0, y)\big)\ $ is an interval of the form $\ (-\infty,a)\ $ where $\ F_X(a)=y\ $.  Putting all this together, we have
\begin{align}
P(U\le y)&=P\big(F_X(X)\le y\big)\\
&=P\big(X\in (-\infty, a)\big)\\
&=F_X(a)\\
&=y\ .
\end{align}